# Tax Class does not appear in product Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3.0, tax-class

I migrated from Magento 1.9.x to Magento 2.3.0.

When editing a product in admin the Tax Class is not shown and is not in any of the expandable sections.

I can see the tax class in the product list (if I add it to the columns) but can see no way of adding it to the product detail edit pages.

Any help would be very much appreciated.